Another step in Granvilles proof of Sylvester-Schur
Here, on the last two pages, Granville presents his proof of the Sylvester-Schur theorem. I have got most of it, and I proved all the little lemmas he uses without proof. Nevertheless, here in the last step there is one inequality I do not get, I rewrote it a little bit:

Finally for the range $k \leq n \leq 3 k / 2$ if prime $p$ is in the range $(n+k) / 3<p \leq k$ then $2 p$ is the only multiple of $p$ that appears in $(n+1) \cdots(n+k)$ and so $p$ does not divide $\binom{n+k}{k}$. Therefore
$$
\frac{4^k}{e k} \leq\binom{2 k}{k} \leq\binom{ n+k}{k} \leq \prod_{p \leq(n+k)^{1 / 2}}(n+k) \prod_{p \leq(n+k) / 3} p \leq \prod_{p \leq(n+k)^{1 / 2}}(3 k)^{\pi\left(2 k^{1 / 2}\right)} \prod_{p \leq 5 k / 6} p\leq (4 k)^{k^{1 / 2}} 4^{5 k / 6-1}
$$
which is false for all $k \geq 1471$.

The first inequality is clear to me. The second one follows as $k\leq n$, the third one is rewriting the binomial coefficient as two products, alright. The second product is less or equal to the last product
$$
\prod_{p \leq(n+k) / 3} p \leq\prod_{p \leq 5 k / 6} p
$$
because $\frac{n+k}{3}\leq \frac{5}{6}k$.

But how on earth do we get
$$
 \prod_{p \leq(n+k)^{1 / 2}}(n+k) \color{red}{\overset{???}{\leq}}  \prod_{p \leq(n+k)^{1 / 2}}(3 k)^{\pi\left(2 k^{1 / 2}\right)}
$$
And how do we end up with $(4 k)^{k^{1 / 2}} 4^{5 k / 6-1}$??

I undestand how to get $4^{5 k / 6-1}$, this is due to
$$
\prod_{p \leq N}p \leq 4^{N-1}.
$$

I mean, it's a funny inequality, but $n+k < 3k$ and $\pi(2k^{1/2}) \ge 1$ so.... I assume the $(4k)^{k^{1/2}}$ comes from somewhere earlier in the argument.
